# “Corrupted” grub, cannot access BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

not long ago I bought an `ACER NITRO 5 512 SSD`, that came with `Endless OS` (some linux distro), after some time i installed `Windows` and override the SSD that was with `Endless O.S`, and then i installed `Elementary O.S` (another linux distro), until this point the grub was working fine with dual boot

going forward i had to install `KDE NEON` (due to some problems of gpu in Elementary OS), in the KDE installation it asks to select a "boot starting point", i always select the "/" option, i was able to install and use KDE normally, but when i rebooted the laptop a "grub terminal" showed up instead of the dual boot screen, i tried changing the boot order in BIOS (accessed BIOS with F2) but no option seemed to work, after some research i was able to boot the KDE with the following commands: (image below)

```
> set root=(hd0,gpt5) 
> linux /boot/vmlinuz.... root=/dev/nvme0n1p5
> initrd /boot/initrd...
> boot
```

[image]

as soon as i logged into KDE i tried to repair the boot with Boot Repair and also manually, both options always seemed to went fine but none of it really worked, the grub terminal continued to appear, and i noticed that more "operational systems" were appearing in the boot order section on BIOS, some even with strange characters, image:

[image]
[image]

i tried the Boot Repair a couple more times, and then one day i tried to access the BIOS and it only showed a black screen with a underscore completely froze, did some research on this and some answers say to format the whole hard drive, i don't know if these 2 problems are related...

this is the output of the command `"fdisk -l"` on KDE:

[image]

should i delete all these partitions (even the EFI and BIOS) using a live linux cd?

Obs: i don't know if this is helpful but i had to enable the `AHCI MODE` on BIOS to boot the linux from a usb stick, when the `AHCI MODE` is selected i cannot boot Windows (it return the blue screen)

how can i solve this?

Comment: You have to first install AHCI drivers into Windows before changing UEFI to AHCI. Change back & update Windows. UEFI remembers installs both in UEFI and in ESP. You show UEFI Secure Boot on. And Acer typically needs "trust" on shimx64.efi boot file. Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969 [SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117

Comment: unfortunately i don`t have access to windows because i cannot access BIOS and change it back to UEFI due to the "black screen with underscore" problem, should i format all partitions and make it like a brand new SSD?

Comment: If UEFI system, you should always be able to boot Windows from UEFI menu, not always from grub as grub only boots working Windows. But you have to change UEFI back to Intel RST/RAID to boot Windows, if you have not added AHCI drivers, yet.

Comment: i cannot access the bios, when i press F2 it just shows a underscore on a black screen

Comment: Did you leave fast boot on in UEFI. That assumes no system changes and immediately boots default again. You have to turn that off when making changes to system. If you cannot get f2 to work, you should be able to do a full "cold" boot. Or totally shutdown system, if laptop remove battery, hold power switch for 10 sec or so to make sure all power is drained. Then boot and immediately press f2 to get into UEFI settings. Assumes f2 is correct key for your system, some use delete key other other key(s).

Comment: i'll try to remove the battery for a few seconds, let's say i'm able to log into the BIOS again, how can i restore my grub and fixe all these operational systems showing there? should i format all my partitions?

Comment: Do not format partitions unless you want to erase all data. You can use efibootmgr to remove UEFI entries and edit /EFI/xxx folders to remove old installs. Examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer

Comment: i was able to reset the battery and the access the BIOS, how can i remove the "wrong" operational systems being listed there?

Comment: You can use efibootmgr to remove UEFI boot entries and the remove folders in the ESP for other systems. Or turn off os-prober and only add (copy) the entries you want into 40_custom.Example removing entries: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi